# Printing all sublists with a reoccurring item in the same index

Tags: python, indexing, sublist

```
Data = [ [0, 'Dev', 'Test1', 0, 0], [0, 'Dev', 'Test2', 0, 0], [0, 'Dev', 'Test3', 0, 0]
          ]

loop = 1
while loop == 1:
#There Is more than one user, they can only see their data
    print ('type name of User')
    User = str(input())
```

This is where the problem resides. The challenge is printing out every occurrence of the user that is being used when in the first Index.

```
try:
    YP = (Data[[value[1] for value in Data].index(User)][2])
    print ('|['+User+'][', YP)
except ValueError:
    print ('No Data')
```

We want an output like this using `Dev`:

```
|[Dev][ Test 1
|[Dev][ Test 2
|[Dev][ Test 3
```

And we want an output like this using other names:

```
No Data
```

But when new data is entered for this other name:

```
|[Ck][ Hello
|[Ck][ Konichiwa
|[Ck][ Bonjour
```

This is how new data is entered:

```
print ('Type = New Data')
NewData = str(input())

PID = len(Data)
PID = (PID - 1)
PID = Data[PID] [0]
PID = (PID + 1)
Data.append([PID, User, NewData, 0, 0])
print (Data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
YP = (Data[[value[1] for value in Data].index(User)][2])
```

`index()` only returns 1 value, the first value it finds, so this line will only ever give you 1 value. Since you want to print all values, you do need a for cycle.

This line is also very hard to read, since it's trying to do a lot at the same time. Don't be afraid to use more lines of code as it often increases the readability of your code.

The first thing i would do is filter the initial data to only get the records that are for the User:

```
UserData = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] == User, Data))
```

This returns the same list as Data, but only the records which have its index 1 equal to our User. If you are using Python 2, `list(...)` is unnecessary since `filter()` already returns a list. But in Python 3 it returns a filter object and we do need to convert it to a list.

If this new list has no elements, there was no data for the user. If it has some elements, we iterate over them and print them:

```
if len(UserData) > 0:
    for data in UserData:
        value = data[2]
        print(f'][{User}][ {value}')
else:
    print('No data')
```

Checking the length of our filtered list to know if we have data is cleaner than relying on an exception to do it for us. Here i'm using [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) to print the data. You could also use the more traditional `format()` function if you feel more comfortable:

```
print('][{}][ {}'.format(User, value))
```

The complete code looks like:

```
UserData = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] == User, Data))

if len(UserData) > 0:
    for data in UserData:
        value = data[2]
        print(f'][{User}][ {value}')
else:
    print('No data')
```

Comment: Thank You, this is exactly what I needed.